# How to show popup only once at 2 days in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, popupwindow

I need a simple code to show a popup window once at 2 days per user using cookies. I have no idea to code in javascript, if somebody can help me.

The code that I have for the popup window is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getValue()
{
document.getElementById("bsadsheadline").style.display = 'none';
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#bsadsheadline').fadeIn(500);
    }, 30000);
});
</script>
<div id="bsadsheadline">
<div id="bloggerspicesflotads">
<span style="color:#fff;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;text-shadow:black 0.01em 0.01em 0.01em"></span>
<span style="color:#fff;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;text-shadow:black 0.01em 0.01em 0.01em;float:right;padding-top:2px;padding-right:115px"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getValue();">inchide(x)</a></span>
</div>
<div id="bsadsbase">
my code
</div></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: java or javascript ??

Comment: hmmm :) ... as I have no idea about java or javascript , I think the code is written in javascript but don`t know for sure :(.

Comment: hmm no your code is written in javascript.and why using cookies ?

Comment: Thank you for telling me that :) ... welll.. because I've seen on some websites that you can do that using cookies, I guess.

Comment: Do you have other ideas ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my solution works using cookies.

Put this in the `<head>` of your page, to make sure [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) (used for displaying the dialogue), and [jQuery Cookie Plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) libraries are loaded:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Put this at the bottom of your page just before the `</body>` tag

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   // Make sure dialog is initially hidden:
   $('#dialog').dialog({autoOpen: false});

    // Check for the "whenToShowDialog" cookie, if not found then show the dialog and save the cookie.
    // The cookie will expire and every 2 days and the dialog will show again.

    if ($.cookie('whenToShowDialog') == null) {

        // Create expiring cookie, 2 days from now:
        $.cookie('whenToShowDialog', 'yes', { expires: 2, path: '/' });

        // Show dialog
        $('#dialog').dialog("open");        
    }

});
</script>
```

Put this in the `<body>` section of your page, and place whatever your want instead of the `<p>` thing.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Test dialog">
  <p>This dialog will only show every 2 days.</p>
</div>
```

if you have any problems, post the link or the html code for your page and I'll help you with inserting this code. I've tested it and it works.

Here's the code example in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/d2s1r0mp/1/

Comment: For me...this is the div that need to be displayed: #bsadsheadline . How can I update my code with your code to make it work ? Thank you.

Comment: Here's the corrected one specifically for your #bsadsheadline:
http://codeshare.io/Tq7Tr.

Make sure you add the 2 lines after your `<head>`, and that there are no duplicated lines (ie jQuery isn't included twice, in case you had it in your HTML before).

Comment: What I posted works. Can you post your complete page code?

Comment: Check now. I have jquery included and all set up.

Comment: I'm sorry you're having problems with implementing my solution. Just looked at your code. Your website's code structure is a huge mess and needs some work to fix!

Comment: Trust me, this solution I posted works, I've used it before on production web applications many times. I just looked at your code again, you already have jQuery & jQuery cookie in the head section. So here's exactly how to fix it: http://codeshare.io/Tq7Tr. I tested it using the console with your website - voila, it works!!

Comment: Thank you a million! . I updated your code a little bit and now it's working as it should. You are a true gentleman! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check Out this code...

```js
if(localStorage.last){
    if( (localStorage.last - Date.now() ) / (1000*60*60*24*2) >= 1){ //Date.now() is in milliseconds, so convert it all to days, and if it's more than 1 day, show the div
        document.getElementById('div#popup').style.display = 'block'; //Show the div
        localStorage.last = Date.now(); //Reset your timer
    }
}
else {
    localStorage.last = Date.now();
    document.getElementById('div#popup').style.display = 'block'; //Show the div because you haven't ever shown it before.
}
```

For full accuracy you will have to use database to maintain the user id and time of block shown to the user. However, if it is not a very hard and fast rule, you can get approximate results by storing the time in browsers cookie, and show/hide the div based on that.

Comment: I have no idea how to put this into my code :( . P.S. I don't want this to work only for the users on my site. I want this to be for all visitors.

Comment: Use the above code inside your script file or inline script tags,
Make sure your div#popup is set to display:none,
This code is not restricted to user, hence it would work for all the visitors..

Answer (score 1):

Adding this code to the head of the page does the job:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Check for the "whenToShowDialog" cookie, if not found then show the dialog and save the cookie.
    // The cookie will expire and every 2 days and the dialog will show again.
    if (jQuery.cookie('whenToShowDialog') == null) {

        // Create expiring cookie, 2 days from now:
        jQuery.cookie('whenToShowDialog', 'yes', { expires: 2, path: '/' });

        // Show dialog
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#bsadsheadline').fadeIn(500);
    }, 30000);       
    }

});
</script>
```

Thanks to @John Valai for helping me.

Answer (score -1):

The code below opens a window in your browser.

```
window.open("url");
```

In terms of opening once every 2 days your best bet is to wrap this in some sort of cron job. No clue why you would be using cookies to open a window.

Comment: I want to use cookies to track the time of a user, if that user is visiting my page the next day , I don't want him to see the popup again, only after 2 days. And I would like to update the code I already have. I tried with this: `if($.cookie('popup') != 'seen'){
    $.cookie('popup', 'seen', { expires: 365, path: '/' }); // Set it to last a year, for example.`    But it didn't worked.